# How constitutional is working for hire?

Tags: united-states, copyright, us-constitution, case-law

In the USA, copyright law may only be established with respect to [the Copyright Clause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copyright_Clause) of the Constitution:

> To promote the Progress of Science and useful Arts, by securing for limited Times to Authors and Inventors the exclusive Right to their respective Writings and Discoveries.

[Working for hire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Work_for_hire) is an established and well-accepted practice currently described by [the 1976 Copyright Act](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copyright_Act_of_1976). However, work-for-hire contracts are commonly used to disenfranchise artists by mandating a reassignment of copyright from employed artists to employers, particularly long-lived corporations. Such reassignments are not necessarily in accord with the Copyright Clause, which only allows for copyrights which "promote the progress of science and useful arts" rather than [seeking rent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rent-seeking), and also only allows for copyrights to be secured "to authors and inventors" rather than employers.

**Has the constitutionality of working for hire been explored?** I'm looking for judicial opinions and case law. State-specific answers are welcome.

Comment: I don't think that laws are usually assessed by whether or not they further a particular purpose, even if that purpose is cited in the Constitution. Certainly, courts do not read the 2nd Amendment that way, even though it too has an explicit purpose, namely "a well regulated Militia." If we did try to assess copyright law based on whether or not it furthers the purpose of "promot[ing] the Progress of Science and useful Arts," we would almost certainly conclude that the term of copyright is so long as to actually _interfere with_ that purpose.

Comment: I wonder why they'd need to. Why can't a business create or invent something? If 500 people get together to film a movie, the movie was created by the whole group of 500.

Comment: The question has not even been asked in the courts. The historical starting point *before* 1976 (or 1909) was that employee product was as a matter of common law the property of the employer. This got statutorily (and vaguely) encoded in 1909, and narrowed in 1976 so that employers do not own *all* works. Your question is ambiguous: maybe you mean "does the work for hire section unconstitutionally burden the employers rights", or maybe "does the work for hire section unconstitutionally burden the employees rights".

Comment: @user253751: But note that a collection of people is not a corporation; the problematic behaviors around copyright start with the [alienation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marx%27s_theory_of_alienation) of artists from their artistic outputs. Contrast a film studio's productions with [reanimations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reanimated_collab) for a vivid example.

Comment: @Corbin A corporation is exactly a collection of people, or at least, that may have been the original intention of the law defining companies. Back then, people would actually pool their money for some kind of collective effort, like a ship expedition, and that expedition was a company, and people got to share the earnings based on how much they put in, which was the shares in the company.

Comment: @user253751: This question isn't about the behavior of businesses, but the beliefs of legislators and judges. It sounds like you might want to ask a fresh question instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> State-specific answers are welcome.

Copyright is exclusively a matter of federal law*, and it in the exclusive jurisdiction of the federal courts. *See* [28 U.S.C. § 1338(a)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/28/1338) ("The district courts shall have original jurisdiction of any civil action arising under any Act of Congress relating to... copyrights .... Such jurisdiction shall be exclusive of the courts of the states in ... copyright cases.").

There are no state specific answers.

> Has the constitutionality of working for hire been explored? I'm
> looking for judicial opinions and case law.

There is no reasonable doubt that the work for hire doctrine is constitutional.

The "work for hire" doctrine arises from [17 U.S.C. § 201(b)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/17/201), which states:

> Works Made for Hire.--In the case of a work made for hire, the
> employer or other person for whom the work was prepared is considered
> the author for purposes of this title, and, unless the parties have
> expressly agreed otherwise in a written instrument signed by them,
> owns all of the rights comprised in the copyright.

Congress has broad discretion to decide who an "author" or "inventor" is under the clause of Article I, Section 8 of the United States Constitution cited in the question. As the U.S. Supreme Court explained in 2020 case:

> “[I]t is generally for Congress, not the courts, to decide how best to
> pursue the Copyright Clause's objectives.” *Eldred v. Ashcroft*, 537
> U.S. 186, 212, 123 S.Ct. 769, 154 L.Ed.2d 683 (2003).

*Georgia v. Public.Resource.Org, Inc.*, [140 S. Ct. 1498](https://casetext.com/case/georgia-v-public-resourceorg-inc), 1511 (2020).

The annotations of court decisions interpreting that statute and interpreting the relevant clause of [Article I, Section 8 of the U.S. Constitution](https://billofrightsinstitute.org/activities/handout-c-article-i-section-8-of-the-u-s-constitution?gad_source=1&gclid=CjwKCAiAkp6tBhB5EiwANTCx1DJLeM8QtCpf3eG8CDWqzQ82UYcOjjC1fg3__HvHxgy-KPAMmp2AUBoCVqUQAvD_BwE), indicate that not a single case has ever even questioned the constitutionality of this part of the copyright statute, which was [enacted in 1976 and took effect in 1978](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copyright_Act_of_1976).

Also, contrary to the assumption made in the question, copyright laws that purely promote and protect rent seeking are constitutionally permitted. The U.S. Supreme Court resolved this question in the case of *Eldred v. Ashcroft*, [537 U.S. 186](https://supreme.justia.com/cases/federal/us/537/186/) (2003), holding that an extension of the term of copyrights still in force, even after the owners of those copyrights were dead, pursuant to the [Sonny Bono Copyright Term Extension Act of 1998](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copyright_Term_Extension_Act), was constitutional. *See also Golan v. Holder*, [565 U.S. 302](https://supreme.justia.com/cases/federal/us/565/302/), 318 (2012) ("The text of the Copyright Clause does not exclude application of copyright protection to works in the public domain.")

- There is one narrow exception to this exclusivity of federal law as of the effective date of the Copyright Act of 1976 in 1978:

> With the 1971, 1976 and subsequent congressional amendments to the
> federal Copyright Act, New York common-law protection of sound
> recordings has been abrogated, but only in two respects. First, the
> common law does not apply to any sound  recording fixed, within the
> meaning of the federal act, after February 15, 1972, because
> recordings made after that date are eligible for federal statutory
> copyright protection. Second, state common-law copyright protection is
> no longer perpetual for sound recordings not covered by the federal
> act (those fixed before February 15, 1972), because the federal act
> mandates that any state common-law rights will cease on February 15,
> 2067. The musical recordings at issue in this case, created before February 15, 1972, are therefore entitled to copyright protection
> under New York common law until the effective date of federal
> preemption — February 15, 2067.

*Capitol Records, Inc. v. Naxos of America, Inc.*, [4 N.Y.3d 540](https://casetext.com/case/capitol-records-inc-v-naxos-of-america-inc-no-30-ny-4-5-2005) (2005) (interpreting the same treaty as *Golan v. Holder*, 565 U.S. 302 (2012), in the context of state law protections for pre-1972 sound recordings).

Hat tip to @bdb484 in the comments.

Comment: There are no state specific answers *after* 1787 - Connecticut had a 1783 copyright law, and [there is an essay on such laws](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1941506). However, the power of federal on all copyright is in Article I, Section 8, Clause 8 of the constitution.

Comment: @Trish Given that the question is asking about the constitutionality of a law enacted in 1976, I think it is fair to say that this issue wasn't a factor. Also, FWIW, the U.S. Constitution took effect in 1789, and state copyright law wasn't fully pre-empted by federal law until 1978 when the Copyright Act of 1976 took effect.

Comment: wait... that reminds me... wasn't there a few month that california had a post-constitutional pre Copyright Act copyright law?

Comment: I think this answer is correct, but I'd quibble with the opening assertion that copyright is exclusively a matter of federal law. There remain narrow areas where common-law copyright protections continue to exist, such as pre-1972 sound recordings. [*Capitol Records, Inc. v. Naxos of America, Inc.*, 4 N.Y.3d 540 (2005)](https://casetext.com/case/capitol-records-inc-v-naxos-of-america-inc-no-30-ny-4-5-2005).

Comment: @bdb484, I had assumed that those copyrights were all spent, but per the case, it sounds like you are right.

Comment: @ohwilleke And I could be wrong, but I think this means that the states could still today extend additional copyright protection above and beyond what the Copyright Act allows. If AI-generated text and images aren't covered, perhaps they could be under some (yet to be enacted) state law?

Comment: @bdb484 I'm not convinced of that.

Comment: Since it gives an answer ("no") and cites relevant cases, I'm accepting this answer; but I don't endorse it.

Comment: @ohwilleke I'm not convinced either. My thinking is that as long as the feds are only saying "this isn't protected by the Copyright Act" (as opposed to "this is in the public domain"), I don't see a strong pre-emption argument. I don't know why that would be wrong, but this isn't my area of expertise.